# Showing intersections with Epilog

Tags: plotting, intersection

I am trying to show the intersections of two curves, using Epilog. But, Epilog doesn't show the points when I gather them in Table. Is there a way to show the points using a Table?

```
gamma4 = .4; gamma3 = .284; gamma2 = .265; gamma1 = .484; z3 = 10000; \
z2 = 32000; z1 = 75000; zbar4 = 4800; zbar3 = 20050; zbar2 = 46200;
zbar1 = 138100; h4 = .301; h3 = .404; h2 = .25;
h1 = .045; p1 = 3.89; p2 = 4.92; p3 = 5.22;
p4 = 5.39; g1 = 0; g2 = 0.44; g3 = 0.88; g4 = 1.76;

Cost2 = (g2 + a (g1 p1 + g3 p3 + g4 p4)) h2 (zbar2 - z2) + (g1 + 
      a (g2 p2 + g3 p3 + g4 p4)) h1 (z1 - z2);
Gain2 = (h2 (zbar2 - z2) + 
    h1 (z1 - z2) + (a (g1 p1 + (g2 p2/\[Tau]2) + g3 p3 + g4 p4) - 
       1) h2 zbar2 gamma2 (\[Tau]2/(1 - \[Tau]2)));

"Finding the intersections"

daSol = NSolve[{Cost2 == Gain2}, {\[Tau]2}]
x[aa_] := daSol /. a -> aa ;
y[aa_] := Cost2 /. a -> aa ;

data = Table[{\[Tau]2 /. x[a], y[a]}, {a, 0, 0.05, 0.05}]

Clear[\[Tau]2]

d0 = Show[
  Plot[Evaluate@Table[ Gain2, {a, 0.05, 0.09, 0.01}], {\[Tau]2, 0, 1},
    PlotLabels -> Placed[ Table[a, {a, 0.05, 0.09, 0.01}], After], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 11000}}, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[data]}] , 
  Plot[Evaluate@Table[Cost2, {a, 0.05, 0.09, 0.01}], {\[Tau]2, 0, 1}, 
   PlotLabels -> Placed[ Table[a, {a, 0.05, 0.09, 0.01}], After]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update** corrected an minor point that managed to stick with me.  See bottom of answer.

---

- OP's question -- showing points of intersection

The glitch is in `data` (you didn't flatten the output in `daSol`).

What happens with daSol containing nested lists is `Table[{\[Tau]2 /. x[a], y[a]}, {a, 0, 0.05, 0.05}]`  results in storing the following in `data`:

> {{{0.561733}, 1562.}, {{0.241936}, 5632.88}}

Notice these aren't coordinates, the "x" value is wrapped in a list which causes the glitch.

Fix goes as follows:

```
data = Table[{\[Tau]2 /. Flatten[x[a]], y[a]}, {a, 0, 0.05, 0.05}]

d0 = Show[
  Plot[Evaluate@Table[Gain2, {a, 0.05, 0.09, 0.01}], {\[Tau]2, 0, 1}, 
   PlotLabels -> Placed[Table[a, {a, 0.05, 0.09, 0.01}], After], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 11000}}, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point @ data}], 
  Plot[Evaluate@Table[Cost2, {a, 0.05, 0.09, 0.01}], {\[Tau]2, 0, 1}, 
   PlotLabels -> Placed[Table[a, {a, 0.05, 0.09, 0.01}], After]]]
```

yields:

[image]

- But....intersection between what curves for lower point?

Although OP solves for intersection with 0 Gain2 and 0 Cost2, including it as an intersection point for Epilog, and didn't plot those curves.  Fixed for my own peace of mind:

```
d0 = Show[
  Plot[Evaluate@Table[Gain2, {a, 0.05, 0.09, 0.01}], {\[Tau]2, 0, 1}, 
   PlotLabels -> Placed[Table[a, {a, 0.05, 0.09, 0.01}], After], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 11000}}, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point@data}], 
  Plot[Evaluate@Table[Cost2, {a, 0.05, 0.09, 0.01}], {\[Tau]2, 0, 1}, 
   PlotLabels -> Placed[Table[a, {a, 0.05, 0.09, 0.01}], After]],
  Plot[{Evaluate@(Cost2 /. a -> 0), 
    Evaluate@(Gain2 /. a -> 0)}, {\[Tau]2, 0, 1}, 
   PlotLabels -> Placed[{0, 0}, After]]]
```

yielding:
[image]